# Retrieving multiple values from json data using typeahead.js

Tags: typeahead.js

I'm having trouble accessing remote json data into [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js). I tried using [prefetch example](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#prefetch) to retrieve notes and be able to search using **typeahead.js**, but was able to fetch only simple json notes with only values.

The json data file I've used is **data/notes_simple.json**.

```
["Atomic Energy", "Introduction to Biology", ...]
```

The search result appears as follows: 
*(Shows only names)*

```
Electromagnetism
Introduction to Biology
```

I want to be able to use **data/notes.json**, which contains **keys** and **values**.

```
[{
    "name": "Electromagnetism",
    "subject": "Physics",
    "form": "4"
}, {
    "name": "Introduction to Biology",
    "subject": "Biology",
    "form": "1"
...
```

The search result I want to appear is as follows: 
*(Shows name, subject and form/class)*

```
Electromagnetism
Physics - Form 4

Introduction to Biology
Biology - Form 1
```

How can I get something like above?

My **js/prefetch.js** looks as below:

```
$(function() {
    var notes = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        limit: 10,
        prefetch: {
            url: 'data/notes_simple.json',
            filter: function(list) {
                return $.map(list, function(country) {
                    return {
                        name: country
                    };
                });
            }
        }
    });

    notes.initialize();

    $('#prefetch .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'notes',
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: notes.ttAdapter()
    });

});
```

You can find my hosted project here: [http://goo.gl/7kPVk2](http://runnable.com/U_iL-HwjtNMYhjlc/notesautosuggest-for-php)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of how you can do something similar can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/u4fq85bj/

You would need to change the remote call to your notes.json, and modify the filter appropriately e.g.

```
remote: {
    url: '/notes.json',
    filter: function (notes) {
        return $.map(notes, function (note) {
            return {
                name: note.name,
                subject: note.subject,
                form: note.form
            };
        });
    }
}
```

To display the results in your desired format you could use the Handlebars template engine with mark-up as follows:

```
templates: {
 suggestion: 
  Handlebars.compile("<p>{{name}}</p><p>{{subject}} - Form {{form}}</i></p>")
    }
```